# What trait need to create an iterator with double dot operator in rust?

Tags: rust

```
use num_integer::{sqrt, Roots};
use num_traits::Unsigned;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

pub fn prime_factorization<T: Unsigned + Roots>(n: T) -> BTreeMap<usize, T> {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    (0..=n.sqrt()).for_each(|v| {});
    map
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:93:10
    |
91  | pub fn prime_factorization<T: Unsigned + Roots>(n: T) -> BTreeMap<usize, T> {
    |                            - this type parameter
92  |     let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
93  |     (0..=n.sqrt()).for_each(|v| {});
    |      ----^^^^^^^^
    |      |   |
    |      |   expected integer, found type parameter `T`
    |      arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note:        expected type `{integer}`
            found type parameter `T`
```

I would like to be able to specify usize,u16,u32,etc for T.
I can specify those types directly, but I would like to know a better way.
What bound should I add to T?

Comment: What does `T` need to be to have `sqrt()`? Don't forget you can always write your own iterator here, or expect that your `T` can be converted `into Range<T>`.

Comment: That’s a range. I wouldn’t try to overload it. Just map the values.

Comment: Or even just a loop. No need for an iterator or a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a range here, you need to do two things.  First, you need some way to convert the literal 0 into your type, since that isn't guaranteed to work for all types.  Second, you need to make it such that your range can be an iterator.

So that would look like this:

```
use num_integer::{sqrt, Roots};
use num_traits::Unsigned;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::iter::Iterator;
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

pub fn prime_factorization<T: Unsigned + Roots + From<u8>>(n: T) -> BTreeMap<usize, T>
    where RangeInclusive<T>: Iterator{
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    (T::from(0)..=n.sqrt()).for_each(|v| {});
    map
}

fn main() {
    prime_factorization(65536u64);
}
```

Comment: It worked fine. Thank you. As a side note, I was trying to implement this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/

Comment: Note that instead of `T: From<u8>`, it might be cleaner to use the [`Zero` trait](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/index.html#reexport.Zero): `T: num_traits::Zero`. This would be required if you wanted to work for both signed and unsigned numbers.